# TikZ: create a button to show something or not

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, button

In some cases I create some (plenty of) buttons of the kind

```
\def\myshow{1}%    1 'yes',    '0' no
```

and then `\ifnum\myshow=1 .... \fi`

But I had to hear, this is not so correct. 
So: What is the correct (and unproblematic) way to create a button like that? Maybe something with `pgfkeys`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\myshow{1}%    1 'yes',    '0' no

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate[label=A](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B](B) at (2,0);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (2,1);

\ifnum\myshow=1
\draw[red, thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\else% nothing
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't find your way particularly wrong, except that you have to be careful with further digits after `1`. I think TeX goes on expanding whatever comes afterwards to see if there are further digits, so you should add `\relax` after `1`. The most basic way is `\newif\ifShow`. This defines commands `\Showtrue` and `\Showfalse` to set or clear the flag, and you can test the flag by `\ifShow ...\else ...\fi`. So your `\def` corresponds to `\newif\ifShow\Showtrue`, and later `\ifShow\draw ...\else\fi`.

Comment: `\show` is an existing important command. Do not overwrite it.

Comment: So better to use '\myshow'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should under no circumstances try to overwrite commands like `\show`, `\meaning`. There is also no need for that. Apart from the `/.is if` key that could be combined with [gernot's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576031/tikz-create-a-button-to-show-something-or-not#comment1450427_576031) there is the `/.is choice` key handler. Here is yet another way which avoids the namespace problems and works with `\ifnum`. Under the hood `tikz` works a bit like this, too.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/cis/.cd,show/.initial=1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate[label=A](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B](B) at (2,0);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (2,1);

\ifnum\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/cis/show}=1
\draw[red, thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\else% nothing
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[/cis/show=0]
\coordinate[label=A](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B](B) at (2,0);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (2,1);

\ifnum\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/cis/show}=1
\draw[red, thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\else% nothing
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for `/.is if`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifcisshow
\tikzset{cis/.cd,show/.is if=cisshow,show/.default=true,show=true}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate[label=A](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B](B) at (2,0);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (2,1);

\ifcisshow
\draw[red, thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\else% nothing
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cis/show=false]
\coordinate[label=A](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B](B) at (2,0);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (2,1);

\ifcisshow
\draw[red, thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\else% nothing
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As mentioned already, `/.is choice` is another option, but this makes most sense if the options are not just Boolean.